# WorkManager: Dependency Issue with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm getting the following error while trying to use Work Manager. I've migrated my project to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn) and all other architecture components are working.

```
def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
/* Work Manager for Background Tasks */
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:$work_version"
```

[image: Error]

I'm quite sure I need some dependencies from the Support Library. But I have no clue which one's they are.

I've tried adding the annotations package since the error says it can't find a class file for RestrictTo$Scope. Still doesn't work.

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha1"
```

Comment: add `-ktx` after `runtime` and `firebase`

Answer (score 1):

You are including a reference to the wrong support library, you want the androidx one.

`androidx.annotation`

Look in
[AndroidX refactoring](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor)

you will find

`androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1`

to correspond with

`com.android.support:support-annotations`

Make sure that you have only libraries for one or the other kind in your dependencies (project wide).